# read write mode python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python open built-in function: difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r)

```
try:
    f = open("file.txt", "r")
    try:
        string = f.read()
        line = f.readline()
        lines = f.readlines()
    finally:
        f.close()
except IOError:
    pass


try:
    f = open("file.txt", "w")
    try:
        f.write('blah') # Write a string to a file
        f.writelines(lines) # Write a sequence of strings to a file
    finally:
        f.close()
except IOError:
    pass
```

Hi,

this is mode which i can read and write file but i want to open file once and perform both read and write operation in python

Comment: [HOLY BLEEPING BLEEP.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r/30931305#30931305

Answer (score 36):

Like in any other programming languages you can open a file in `r+`, `w+` and `a+` modes.

- `r+` opens for reading and writing (no truncating, file pointer at the beginning)
- `w+` opens for writing (and thus truncates the file) and reading
- `a+` opens for appending (writing without truncating, only at the end of the file, and the file pointer is at the end of the file) and reading

Answer (score 12):

From the [doc](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> `r+`: opens the file for both reading and writing

Comment: thanks but when i used r+ its appending file, i don't want to append

Comment: @Styendra you need to use f.seek(0) before the call to f.write() (f is the opened file object) otherwise f.read() will leave the position counter at the end of the file and that's where f.write() will pick up.